# Squid Proxy using HTTPS

Tags: ssl, proxy, https, squid, transparent-proxy

So i have squid proxy setup and running fine with HTTP but now i need it to work with HTTPS. i already have a self signed certificate using my own root CA which is installed on my pc, and a key as well. The only issue is that all the guides that i have found on how to configure squid to use HTTPS is that you need this sslbump file.

BUT ITS NOT THERE!

When i installed squid on my ubuntu 18.04 server the /usr/lib/squid folder doesnt have the sslbump file, here is a list of all the files that are there:

> basic_db_auth*        basic_radius_auth*  ext_file_userip_acl*          helper-mux.pl*                 pinger*
>   basic_fake_auth*      basic_sasl_auth*    ext_kerberos_ldap_group_acl*  log_db_daemon*                 storeid_file_rewrite*
>   basic_getpwnam_auth*  basic_smb_auth*     ext_ldap_group_acl*           log_file_daemon*               unlinkd*
>   basic_ldap_auth*      basic_smb_auth.sh*  ext_session_acl*              negotiate_kerberos_auth*       url_fake_rewrite*
>   basic_ncsa_auth*      cert_tool*          ext_sql_session_acl*          negotiate_kerberos_auth_test*  url_fake_rewrite.sh*
>   basic_nis_auth*       digest_file_auth*   ext_time_quota_acl*           negotiate_wrapper_auth*
>   basic_pam_auth*       digest_ldap_auth*   ext_unix_group_acl*           ntlm_fake_auth*
>   basic_pop3_auth*      diskd*              ext_wbinfo_group_acl*         ntlm_smb_lm_auth*

Now i dont know if the name changed or whatever but its doesnt seem like it did (based on the guides and tutorials that i found).

Can someone please help me, ant help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You need to compile the squid from source code with --enable-ssl-crtd --with-openssl, or simply install squid from this ppa https://github.com/diladele/squid-ubuntu, it already compiled with ssl enabled.

Answer (score -1):

compiling from source is required otherwise use one of the pre-compiled images, if you plan to use this as a VM on vmware or virtualbox you can use the proxyeg bundle, [www.proxyeg.com](https://www.proxyeg.com/squidva/) This is squid, ClamAV and SSL options all enabled by default and installed on Ubuntu.

Comment: This site can’t be reachedCheck if there is a typo in www.proxyeg.com.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN